# Copy and Pasting Sequential Cell Values from Excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, pyautogui

I am relatively new to using python. I am trying to write a script that will copy a specific value from a spreadsheet (E.g. A1), allow me to paste this using pyautogui into a search bar in a database that I'm using and then copy text in a specific location into the cell next to A1 i.e. B1.

I then want to repeat this search but this time the value from A2 copying the resultant text into B2.

So far I have this (See below) but I am getting stuck at the point at which it copies this into the search bar as it is just looping all the values within the spreadsheet into the search bar all at once. Please can somebody help. Thank you in advance and I hope this makes sense.

```
import pyautogui
import openpyxl
import pyperclip

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
max_row = sheet.max_row
max_column = sheet.max_column

def start_program():
    # Opens Chrome by clicking icon in toolbar
    pyautogui.click(925, 774)

    # Clicks in Google Search bar
    pyautogui.click(638, 577)

    #Pauses module for 3 seconds
    pyautogui.sleep(3)


def loop_excel_sheet():
    for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
        for j in range(1, max_column + 1):
            cell_obj = sheet.cell(row=i, column=j)
            pyperclip.copy(str(cell_obj.value))
            pyautogui.typewrite(pyperclip.paste())


start_program()
loop_excel_sheet()
```

Comment: It seems like you loop through the entire spreadsheet in loop_excel_spreadsheet, why dont you put a pyautogui function inside your loop_excel_sheet function. so somewhere inside loop_excel_sheet you also search and output, or else all the information will dump at the end. additionally maybe use print statement so see what your loop is doing.

Comment: Hi stackaccount, would you be able to give me an example?